# extern "c" behaviour in linux platform

Tags: c++, linux, header-files, extern

```
ScriptInterface.h

extern "C"
{
#include "kel.h"
#include "process.h"
#if defined(SIMULATOR_COMPILE_FROM_SCRIPTINTERFACE) || defined(SIMULATOR_WIN)
#include "sigtypes.h"
#endif
}
```

In windows platform this is not giving any errors(below code)

```
xyz.cpp

#include "kel.h"
#include "process.h"
#include "sigtypes.h"

#include "ScriptInterface.h"
```

Whereas it is giving 'Symbol look up error' in Linux platform. Is there any different behavior of extern 'C' in Linux platform?

Comment: You should provide more info. How are you compiling it? What's the exact error message? And so on.

Comment: I am running a script file which takes  care of compiling xyz.cpp file.

Comment: error message : symbol lookup error: xyz.so: undefined symbol: _Z16KEL_MEM_AllocateP19KEL_MEM_tPoolHandlej

Comment: If you use [demangler.com](http://demangler.com/) it'll tell you the missing code is `KEL_MEM_Allocate(KEL_MEM_tPoolHandle*, unsigned int)`... you obviously have a `kel.h` and it's a pretty fair guess that the declaration of that function's in there somewhere.  Notice that `xyz.cpp` includes `kel.h` before including `ScriptInterface.h` and ***without wrapping the include of `kel.h` with `extern "C"`*** - that's likely your error.

Comment: But why it is not giving any error in windows? I use VS 2005.

Comment: @TonyD -: why it is not giving any error in windows? I use VS 2005.

Comment: @user3267021: Coincidence, luck, you name it. You should use `extern "C"` only around declarations of C functions, and clearly `kel.h` can't declare at the same time C and C++ functions.

Comment: @user3267021 I don't know - I try not to work in Visual Studio if I have any choice... my best guess is it's a side effect of the way VS handles 'precompiled headers' (i.e. it's precompiled them as C then suppresses the includes from xyz.cpp in favour of consulting the metadata from precompilation).  And VS 2005?  Ouch!  Legendarily poor C++03 Standard support, and time for an upgrade....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`_Z16KEL_MEM_AllocateP19KEL_MEM_tPoolHandlej` is very much a mangled name and it's almost certainly there because you're including `kel.h` *outside* of the `extern "C"` block.

Get rid of the first three includes in `xyz.cpp` and just use the ones you include from within `ScriptInterface.h` (which are marked as non-mangling).

Comment: Out of interest, what makes you think that the OP is using a C compiler?

Comment: @NPE: the fact that the question has a C tag :-)

Comment: But the filename has a `.cpp` extension, that's for C++.

Comment: Yes, but that's in the bit talking about Windows platform. And, in fact, extern "C" works fine in Linux if you use g++ rather than gcc.

Comment: To me it seems rather likely that the question is mistagged. I could be wrong.

Comment: @paxdiablo If i remove those header files from xyz.cpp it will not give any error in linux! but in windows with include of these three header files not give any error? why?